# Cast VLC audio to DLNA device

Tags: audio, vlc, dlna

It seems that VLC on Android is able to cast to a ChromeCast device, although I don't have one to actually test that.

Is it also possible to cast (audio) to a DLNA device? If it matters, it's an [AudioCast M5](https://audiocast.io/).